# Solving the complex equation $|z|+z=6-2i$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have to tackle the following question. My thoughts so far are below it.

> Given that $z$ is the complex number $x+iy$ and that $|z|+z=6-2i$, find the value of $x$ and the value of $y$.

What I only know is that $|z|=r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

So how should I continue to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key realization is that $|z|$ is always a real number.

---

So if we subtract $|z|$ from both sides, we see, grouping real and imaginary parts together,

$$z = (6 - |z|) + (-2)i$$

So, since $z = x+iy$ and the imaginary part of both sides must be equal, we can conclude $y=-2$. This also means $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + (-2)^2} = \sqrt{x^2+4}$.

So, substituting in everything we know back into our original equation.

$$\sqrt{x^2+4} + x -2i = 6 - 2i$$

Add $2i$ to both sides and we get

$$\sqrt{x^2+4} + x = 6$$

This is a relatively simple algebraic equation to solve; once you do, you will have your $x$. (Be sure to check the $x$ you get: solving the equation above will introduce extraneous solutions!)

Comment: That should be $x^2$ inside the square root, not $x$.

Comment: Be careful: $z=\sqrt{x^2+4}$

Comment: awwww got it ! Thank you guys！！

Comment: Thanks jmerry and Rhys; should be fixed now. That's what I get for being hasty lol

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $z=r(\cos2t+i\sin2t)$ where $r
>0,t$ are real and $0\le2t<2\pi$

Equate the Real & the imaginary parts

$r(1+\cos2t)=6$  and $r\sin2t=-2$

On division $\tan t=-\dfrac26$

Use https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/WeierstrassSubstitution.shtml

to find $\cos2t,\sin2t$

Then can you find $r?$